# Why is vue-chartjs not showing my passed data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-chartjs

working on a covid app to get familiar with vue2js.

Am now trying to get a graph with vue-chartjs but am failing to pass the data to the graph/chart component.

I make an API request with vuex and passing the data to my component: CountryGraph.vue which contains a Graph.vue with the chart itself.

vuex -> CountryGraph.vue -> Graph.vue

Passing data into CountryGraph.vue works:

[image: Data from vuex into CountryGraph.vue]

But when I try to pass my data (`countryGraph`) as props to my char/Graph.vue component, then it is not done and I get in Graph.vue only the value `undefined`:

[image: LineChart Undefined]

Why?

Below my code, first the CountryGraph.vue:

```
<template>
    <section class="countryGraph">
        <LineChart
            :chartdata="chartData"
            :options="chartOptions"
        />
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
import LineChart from "../graph/Graph";

export default {
    name: "CountryGraph",
    components: { LineChart },

    data: () => ({
        chartData: {
            labels: this.countryGraph.map((el) => el.date),
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Confirmed",
                    backgroundColor: "#f87979",
                    data: this.countryGraph.map(
                        (el) => el.confirmed
                    ),
                },
            ],
        },
        chartOptions: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
        },
    }),

    methods: {
        ...mapActions(["selectCountryGraph"]),
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["countryGraph"]),
    },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

And my chart/Graph.vue component which is made so, that I can reuse it (as stated in [vue-chartjs guide](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#chart-with-api-data)):

```
<script>
import { Bar } from "vue-chartjs";

export default {
    extends: Bar,

    props: {
        chartdata: {
            type: Object,
            default: null,
        },
        options: {
            type: Object,
            default: null,
        },
    },

    mounted() {
        this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options);
    },
};
</script>

<style />
```

---

When I use mocked data, like instead of

```
labels: this.countryGraph.map((el) => el.data)
```

I do `labels: ["q", "w", "e", "r", "t"]`
and instead of

```
data: this.countryGraph.map(el => el.confirmed)
```

I do `data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

everything works fine.

Also, when I pass my variables directly into the component, like:

```
<LineChart
            :chartdata="this.countryGraph.map((el) => el.data)"
            :options="chartOptions"
        />
```

Then I can see the data as props in the child (Graph.vue) component.
But in this case I use `v-bind:` and in the earlier one not. Maybe that is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple issues to note:

1. It looks like you're mapping a nonexisting property (`el.data` should be `el.date`). Possibly just a typo in the question.

   ```js
   this.countryGraph.map((el) => el.data) ❌
                                       ^
   ```
2. `data()` is not reactive, and cannot rely on computed props, so the `countryGraph` computed prop will not be available in `data()` and will not update `chartData` with changes. One way to fix this is to make `chartData` a computed prop:

   ```js
   export default {
       computed: {
           ...mapGetters(["countryGraph"]),
           // don't use an arrow function here, as we need access to component instance (i.e., this.countryGraph)
           chartData() {
             return {
                 labels: this.countryGraph.map((el) => el.date),
                 datasets: [
                     {
                         label: "Confirmed",
                         backgroundColor: "#f87979",
                         data: this.countryGraph.map((el) => el.confirmed),
                     },
                 ],
             }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: 1. Yes, you are right. Corrected it. Thanks!
Also thanks for telling me about computed propertys! This was for now my missing piece of information. Now I will be able to use logic in a more structured way.